# How do I add an exception to a query that finds the most popular records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a website where users submit screencasts and associate with them, tags.

Here are the 3 tables that comprise the database:

```
Screencasts:

| screencastId | title                                            |
|--------------|--------------------------------------------------|
| CF9S4QZuV30  | Go Programming                                   |
| ef-6NZjBtW0  | How to Make Android Apps                         |
| F3WpBsc0QEw  | Git & GitHub: Creating a Repository (2/11)       |
| Ggh_y-33Eso  | Learn HTML in 15 Minutes                         |
| GrycH6F-ksY  | jQuery Tutorials: Submitting a Form with AJAX    |
| N4mEzFDjqtA  | Python Programming                               |
| QRmmISj6Rrw  | Learn PHP: Your first file                       |
| WPvGqX-TXP0  | Java Programming                                 |
| wz3kElLbEHE  | SASS Tutorial                                    |
| Xx-XZwJT76w  | Setting Up A Development Environment With Bowery |

Tags:

| tagName |
|---------|
| Android |
| Bowery  |
| Git     |
| Go      |
| Html    |
| Java    |
| jQuery  |
| PHP     |
| Python  |
| Sass    |


ScreencastTags

| screencastId | tagName |
|--------------|---------|
| CF9S4QZuV30  | Go      |
| ef-6NZjBtW0  | Android |
| ef-6NZjBtW0  | Java    |
| F3WpBsc0QEw  | Git     |
| Ggh_y-33Eso  | Html    |
| GrycH6F-ksY  | jQuery  |
| N4mEzFDjqtA  | Python  |
| QRmmISj6Rrw  | PHP     |
| WPvGqX-TXP0  | Java    |
| wz3kElLbEHE  | Sass    |
| Xx-XZwJT76w  | Bowery  |
```

The website allows the user to view the **9** most popular tags:

[image]

The query I use to determine these 9 most popular tags is as follows:

```
SELECT t.tagName
FROM tags t
JOIN screencastTags m
    ON m.tagName = t.tagName
GROUP BY t.tagName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, t.tagName DESC
LIMIT 9
```

As you can see, there is a **10th** menu item entitled **Other**. When clicked, the user is shown screencasts whose tags are **not** among the 9 most popular.

The query I use to determine these screencasts is as follows:

```
SELECT
    v.screencastId,
    v.title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(m.tagName) as tags
FROM screencasts v
JOIN screencastTags m
    ON v.screencastId = m.screencastId
WHERE m.tagName NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT t.tagName
        FROM tags t
        JOIN screencastTags m
            ON m.tagName = t.tagName
        GROUP BY t.tagName
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, t.tagName DESC
        LIMIT 9) as t)
GROUP BY v.screencastId
ORDER BY v.ReferralCount DESC
```

Unfortunately, this query does behave as I would have hoped. It results in the following table:

```
| screencastId | title                    | tagName |
|--------------|--------------------------|---------|
| ef-6NZjBtW0  | How to Make Android Apps | Android |
```

I wanted it to return this table:

```
| screencastId | title                    | tagName       |
|--------------|--------------------------|---------------|
| ef-6NZjBtW0  | How to Make Android Apps | Android, Java |
```

**How do I achieve the expected result in this case?**

As you can see, the subquery returns the 9 most popular tags, among them is the tag **Java**. Because the query returns screencasts whose tags are **not** in the subquery result, the tag **Java** is not included. It should be, because the screencast was tagged as **Android** *and* **Java**. **Android** is not one of the 9 most popular tags, **Java** is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want screen casts that have none of the 9 tags, then the logic is more like this:

```
SELECT v.screencastId, v.title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(m.tagName) as tags
FROM screencasts v JOIN
     screencastTags m
     ON v.screencastId = m.screencastId LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t.tagName
      FROM tags t JOIN
           screencastTags m
           ON m.tagName = t.tagName
      GROUP BY t.tagName
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, t.tagName DESC
      LIMIT 9
     ) tags9
     ON m.tagname = tags9.tagname
GROUP BY v.screencastId, v.title
HAVING SUM(tags9.tagname IS NOT NULL) = 0;
```

What is this doing?  The `LEFT JOIN` is matching tags to the nine original tags (assuming the database has not been updated between the two queries).  The aggregation is by the screen case.  The `HAVING` clause then checks that there is no match to the nine tags.  This guarantees that none of the nine tags are one the returned values from this query.

EDIT:

Ooops, I think I misinterpreted the question.  I thought you wanted screen casts that have none of the nine tags.  Instead, you want all the tags for screen casts that have additional tags.

This is actually a small variation on the above query.  Instead of checking that *all* tags are different, this checks that *any* tag is different.  The only change is to the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT v.screencastId, v.title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(m.tagName) as tags
FROM screencasts v JOIN
     screencastTags m
     ON v.screencastId = m.screencastId LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t.tagName
      FROM tags t JOIN
           screencastTags m
           ON m.tagName = t.tagName
      GROUP BY t.tagName
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, t.tagName DESC
      LIMIT 9
     ) tags9
     ON m.tagname = tags9.tagname
GROUP BY v.screencastId, v.title
HAVING SUM(tags9.tagname IS NULL) > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Gordon. I really appreciate it. I am testing this out now however, I get this error: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'm.tags' in 'on clause'`.

Comment: I changed that line to `ON m.tagName = tags9.tagname` and the query returns no rows :(.

Comment: @Angularnoob . . . That suggests that all screen casts have at least one of the nine original tags.

Comment: They do. The `ScreencastTags` table has two rows for the id `ef-6NZjBtW0`  mapping to **Android** (not one of the 9) and **Java** (one of the 9). Again, thank you.